# Accessibility issue in ng-select

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

For accessibility testing I am using axe tool where I am getting below error.

Required ARIA child role not present: option

This is my code where I am using angular ng-select:

```
<ng-select [items]="rolesList" bindLabel="roleName" placeholder="Select Role" [(ngModel)]="role" aria-label="role" id="rolesList" tabindex="0">
</ng-select>
```

Answer (score 2):

**ng-select** uses their custom `bindLabel` Input in order to automatically populate the aria accessibility. **aria-label** isn't used, instead **aria-role** is used to describe that it is an option or group as expected. You can add a parent div with **aria-label** if you feel it is a necessity to have a screen reader describe the select in further detail, but **aria-own** and **aria-activedescendent** tags are added. Please see this merged PR for more information on the source of how these tags are used: https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/pull/433/files

Note: There are also known issues with specific screen readers (such as aXe) as described here: https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/pull/1026. There has been some custom work to enhance the usage but it was never merged.